# Eclipse Mars Javascript validator on Angular services

Tags: javascript, eclipse, validation

On Eclipse validator the  keywords "finally" and "catch" seems not allowed:

```js
$http.get(url)
.success(function (data) {
    // Handle data
})
.error(function (data, status) {
    // Handle HTTP error
})
.finally(function () {
    // Execute logic independent of success/error
});
```

On line 8 (.finally...) the validator says "Syntax error on token "finally", Identifier expected".
If I remove the finally block, the error disappears.

Is there a way to say eclipse that this is not an error without disabling the complete validation?

regards
Bytecounter

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java).

Your problem comes from JSDT Validator which doesn't support ES5 syntax. I suggest you that you [install tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) which provides the capability to validate your JS file with JSHint https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter-JSHint which is able to validate ES5/ES6 syntax.

Before using this validator, you must disable JSDT Validator (see [EcmaScript 6 - Tern IDE for Eclipse validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479015/ecmascript-6-tern-ide-for-eclipse-validation-errors/33480168#33480168))