# EcmaScript 6 - Tern IDE for Eclipse validation errors

Tags: eclipse, ecmascript-6, tern

I am using Eclipse Mars with the Tern IDE für ES6 support on version 1.1.0 (the snapshot). I get validation errors on arrow functions and const-exports as can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]

I worked through these descriptions but the errors won't vanish: 
https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-ECMAScript6-support
https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter

I don't know however whats really supported by the Tern plugin, but according to the documentation on http://ternjs.net/ Tern should support arrow functions since 0.14. The IDE-page on github however only mentions class, import and promise support (which is beyond basic in my eyes for a plugin to support ES6).

Is there anyone who is developing ES6 with Eclipse with (more or less) full feature support? I kinda feel like a unicorn...

Comment: > only mentions class, import and promise support (which is beyond basic in my eyes for a plugin to support ES6). @Ahab ternjs supports more ES6 features like ES modules, etc. See https://github.com/ternjs/tern/issues/116#issuecomment-131781238 I had no time to update the wiki with thoses features, any help are welcome to update the wiki.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error comes from JSDT Validator which doesn't support ES6 syntax (and not from tern).

tern 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT provides support for ES6 for completion, hyperlink, validation but not for ES6 validation. The linter https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter is a type checker validator and not a syntax validator.

To validate ES6 with Eclipse IDE & tern.java, you must:

- disable JSDT Validator. For that you can remove the JSDT nature from your .project. Or install (never tested) the not released Eclipse JEE distribution which provides **an option to turn off internal parsing** and validation. See http://tools.jboss.org/documentation/whatsnew/jbosstools/4.3.0.Final.html#javascript-development-tools-improvements
- after that, you can use JSHint to validate ES6, with https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Linter-JSHint. To enable JSHint to validate ES6 correctly it needs to get the "esnext"-option enabled otherwise ES6 syntax will be marked as errors. The option is found in the project properties\Tern\Validation\JSHint under "Relaxing options".

Comment: Thanks a lot so far! I in deed did the approach with switching to an "External Builder/Validator" but the nature still kept the errors somehow, removing the nature ultimately switched off the validation.

Comment: @Ahab could you add a comment at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472754 with your problem with "External Builder/Validator" Thanks!

Comment: I added a comment on your linked bug report. Maybe you could implement some kind of validation include/exclude functionality? Validation on JSHint takes forever although I excluded my node_modules from build path of JSDT initially.

Comment: For Validation on JSHint, please create issues at https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/issues and please share your project which caues problem.