# Eclipse JSDT Object Literal and firefox

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdt

I'm using the Eclipse editor with JSDT to work through some Firefox add-on examples. The following code generates errors.

```
const {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");

var downloadManager = Cc["@mozilla.org/download-manager;1"]
.getService(Ci.nsIDownloadManager);
```

The first line gives the error - Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

The last line gives the error - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block

Is there something wrong with this code or is it JSDT that is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using ES6 syntax code and JSDT Validator doesn't support this ECMA version  (so it's a problem with JSDT). Your issue is the same than [EcmaScript 6 - Tern IDE for Eclipse validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479015/ecmascript-6-tern-ide-for-eclipse-validation-errors)